# Refactor a java AsyncTask to use RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have an AsyncTask that I am trying to modify to make use of [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)'s event system. My code is not working and I am new to RxJava - can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Here is the original AsyncTask code:

```java
public void getData(String str) {
  new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
    public String doInBackground(String... strArr) {
      try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(
            ((HttpURLConnection) new URL(strArr[0]).openConnection())
              .getInputStream()
          )
        );
        while (true) {
          String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
          if (readLine == null) {
            return sb.toString().trim();
          }
          sb.append(readLine + "\n");
        }
      } catch (Exception unused) {
        return null;
      }
    }
    public void onPostExecute(String str) {
      MainActivity.this.myJSON = str;
      MainActivity.this.showList();
    }
  }.execute(new String[]{str});
}
```

And here is my attempt to rewrite it:

```java
public void BackgroundTask(String str) {
  backgroundtask = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
    try {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      URL url = new URL(str);
      URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
      InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      /*BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
          ((HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLs).openConnection())
            .getInputStream()
        )
      );*/
      while (true) {
        String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        if (readLine == null) {
          return sb.toString().trim();
        }
        sb.append(readLine + "\n");
      }
    }
    catch (Exception unused) {
      return null;
    }
  })
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe((result) -> {
    MainActivity.this.myJSON = result;
    MainActivity.this.showList();
    backgroundtask.dispose();
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi there. It will help people answer your question if you also include the errors or incorrect results you're running into. Please take a look at [How To Ask A Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - The better the question, the better your answers are more likely to be. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your RxJava code seems to be correct. Maybe u can try to use **Observer** instead of **Consumer**, if it's something wrong, u can check the method

```
    /**
 * Notifies the Observer that the {@link Observable} has experienced an error condition.
 * <p>
 * If the {@link Observable} calls this method, it will not thereafter call {@link #onNext} or
 * {@link #onComplete}.
 *
 * @param e
 *          the exception encountered by the Observable
 */
void onError(@NonNull Throwable e);
```

Answer (score 0):

RxJava does not support `null` types. When you return null, you will get an exception.

Also, you don't need to try catch the callable code. When the error occurs, it will be passed to the error consumer.

You could rewrite the code like this (I assume you use Java 8 or higher):

```
Single<String> task(@NonNull String str) {
    return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
        URL url = new URL(str);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        return bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    });
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
task("url argument")
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        result -> { /*Do something with the result*/},
        error ->  { /*Log the error*/}
    );
```